Как через bat файл запустить сначала BitComet, а потом ngrok и в него ввести команду ngrok tcp "нужный мне порт"?
@Echo off
cd "C:\Program Files\BitComet"
start BitComet.exe
cd "C:\Users\FyrekS\Desktop"
start ngrok.exe

Как через bat файл запустить сначала BitComet, а потом ngrok и в него ввести команду ngrok tcp "нужный мне порт"? Не знаю что писать после start ngrok.exe.

нашел в инете, что не start ngrok.exe а ngrok tcp/http/udp.... port

Где-то встречал метод
echo ngrok tcp "порт">ngrok.exe

Но это испортит сам ngrok, так что не вариант.
